# How to get Position of Components using React Function Components

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

When I click on a card on the left and then ctrl+click on a card on the right.. a line will be drawn.  Ctrl+click on the card on the right again and the line will be removed. I'm going to draw the line using an svg path but I have to get the positions of the cards in the **Container Component** to do so.

I'm trying to do this with React Function Components using ref and I'm not quite getting it.  I understand that function components don't have an "instance" and therefore ref doesn't work quite like it does in classes.

Please answer the following:

- Is it possible to do this with just function components?
- Which components require to be wrapped in React.forwardRef()?
- I read that I can just pass a function from the Container to the children in the ref attribute and the children can call that function when clicked.  Is that true and what would that look like?
- bonus: I've read through the [React Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) documentation several times and it just won't click for me. Can anyone explain it in my context?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This is what I have so far:

**ContainerComponent**

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

import { Container, Row, Col, Card, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import SectionContainer from './SectionContainer';

const ContainerComponent = (props) => 
{
    const [keyCards, setKeyCards] = useState([
        { id: 1, name: 'key one', description: "this is a key card for one" },
        { id: 2, name: 'key two', description: "this is a key card for two" }
    ])

    const [valueCards, setValueCards] = useState([
        { id: 1, name: 'value one', description: "this is a value card" },
        { id: 2, name: 'value two', description: "this is a value card" },
        { id: 3, name: 'value three', description: "this is a value card" }
    ])

    const [connections, setConnections] = useState([
        // I need something like this for all connections that need a line
        {
            keyID: 1,
            keyPos: { x: 100, y: 200 },
            attachedValues: [
                { valueID: 1, valPos: { x: 200, y: 200 } },
                { valueID: 2, valPos: { x: 200, y: 300 } }
            ]
        }
    ])

    const cardRef = useRef()

    const getPositions = () =>
    {
        console.log(cardRef.current)
        // if I can get positions and if they are selected
        // then I can set the state and generate svg paths
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Row >
                <Col className="display-section" md='6'>
                    <SectionContainer
                        title="Rules for Life"
                        items={keyCards}
                        cardRef={cardRef}
                        onClickHandler={getPositions}
                    />
                </Col>

                <Col className="display-section" md='6'>
                    <SectionContainer
                        title="Entitlements for Days"
                        items={valueCards}
                        cardRef={cardRef}
                        onClickHandler={getPositions}
                    />
                </Col>
            </Row>
            {/* <DrawLines connections={connections} /> */}
        </>
    )
}

export default ContainerComponent
```

**SectionContainer**

```
import React from 'react';

import { Row, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, InputGroupText } from 'reactstrap';

import CardContainer from './CardContainer'

const SectionContainer = ({ title, items, cardRef, onClickHandler }) => 
{
    return (
        <>
            <h6>{title}</h6>
            <Row >
                <InputGroup>
                    <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend" >
                        <InputGroupText>filter:</InputGroupText>
                    </InputGroupAddon>
                    <Input />
                </InputGroup>
            </Row>
            <CardContainer
                items={items}
                cardRef={cardRef}
                onClickHandler={onClickHandler}
            />
        </>
    )
}

export default SectionContainer
```

**Card Container**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container, Row } from 'reactstrap'
import CardComponent from './CardComponent'

const CardContainer = ({ items, cardRef, onClickHandler }) => 
{
    const getItems = (items) =>
    {
        return items.map(item =>
        {
            return <Row key={item.id}>
                <CardComponent
                    item={item}
                    cardRef={cardRef}
                    onClickHandler={onClickHandler}
                />
            </Row>
        })
    }
    return (
        <Container fluid className="node-container">
            {getItems(items)}
        </Container>
    )
}

export default CardContainer
```

**Card Component**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { Card, CardHeader, CardTitle, CardBody, CardText } from 'reactstrap';

const CardComponent = React.forwardRef(({ item, cardRef, onClickHandler }, ref) => 
{
    return (
        <Card ref={cardRef} >
            <CardHeader onClick={onClickHandler} >
                <CardTitle>{item.name}</CardTitle>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
                <CardText>{item.description}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>)
})

export default CardComponent
```

This displays the cards similar to the drawing above no problem.  I just can't get the ref thing to work.

I'm getting the following error for CardComponent even tho I have wrapped it with React.ForwardRef():

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access
> this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
>
> Check the render method of `ForwardRef`.
> in Card (at CardComponent.js:8)
> ...

**Edit**

I fixed the forwardRef() error by wrapping my Card in a div. Even tho the bootstrap Card renders as a div, you can't ref it.

Only one position is passing up to the ContainerComponent tho.  Still working on that.

**New CardComponent**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { Card, CardHeader, CardTitle, CardBody, CardText } from 'reactstrap';

const CardComponent = ({ item, cardRef, onClickHandler }) =>
    (
        <div ref={cardRef}>
            <Card >
                <CardHeader onClick={onClickHandler} >
                    <CardTitle>{item.name}</CardTitle>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                    <CardText>{item.description}</CardText>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        </div>
    )


export default CardComponent
```

Comment: Yes, depends, true, you haven't given us any context. Please show specific attempts or problems or even better provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we may engage with to help you.

Comment: @pilchard I felt like my attempts were not close enough to help with answering my question but I will add what I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here. I owe it to the community since my question was pretty vague. Big thanks to @dlya for his answer which led me down the path to righteousness :)

- Is it possible to do this with just function components?

Yes. I was able to complete the task end to end without classy components.

- Which components require to be wrapped in React.forwardRef()?

None. I didn't end up having to use React.forwardRef() at all. In fact... I didn't use useRef() or useEffect() either. I just passed a function to the child and added the function to the ref like this:

```
<Card innerRef={updateCardLocations} id={`${type}-${item.id}`}>
```

Notice that I had to use innerRef instead of ref because I really needed to get the reactstrap ref instead of having to wrap Card in a div.

Then I just collect all of my Card positions in the parent like this:

```
    let connections = {}

    const updateCardLocations = (card) =>
    {
        if (card)
        {
            const id = card.id.substr(card.id.indexOf("-") + 1)
            const pos = card.getBoundingClientRect()

            connections[id] = {
                ...connections[id],
                connectionPoint: [pos.right, pos.top + (pos.height / 2)]
            }

            console.log(connections)
        }
    }
```

- I read that I can just pass a function from the Container to the children in the
  ref attribute and the children can call that function when clicked. Is that true and what would that look like?

I just showed what that looks like in the previous bullet. The parent has a function called updateCardLocations which is passed as a prop to the child.  Pass the updateCardLocations function prop to a ref in the Child. In my case innerRef.

- bonus: I've read through
  the React Refs and the DOM documentation several times and it just
  won't click for me. Can anyone explain it in my context?

What I was missing from the documentation was that you're just creating a placeholder in the parent that you pass to the child component as a prop. Then when the child component is rendered it updates that placeholder with it's dom information. I don't fully grasp things until I can get a successful hands on experience... but in my defense, the whole forwardRef thing really confused me because I couldn't tell which direction I was forwarding the ref and at that time I still thought that I had created a ref in the parent as well with useRef(). Hopefully this helps someone that is as easily confused as me :)

Here's a [working sample on CodeSandbox](https://149j7.csb.app/). I also included an onClickHandler that adds cards and you can see the positions updating in the console.

Answer (score 2):

Using react hooks you can basically do anything that you did in a class component in a functional component.

I guess you can get the position using [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
//import Card from '.../...';

const App = () =>
{
    const cardRef = useRef();

    const onClickHandler = () =>
    {
        const position = cardRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        //This returns an object with left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, and height.
        console.log(position)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Card cardRef={cardRef} onClickHandler={onClickHandler} />
        </div>
    );

}

export default App

const Card = ({ cardRef, onClickHandler }) => (
    <div ref={cardRef} onClick={onClickHandler}>
        <button > Click Me </button>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: This works good.  Now I just have to figure out how to get it to work in my more complex use case.  Do you have any tips on the right way to pass refs up 3 levels or is what I'm doing ok?

Comment: You can always use the [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) if you want to make any variable global but in your case, I don't think it's ideal @pnkflydgr

Comment: I ended up having to use state management.  it got way to complicated to pass refs around.  But I'm glad I know how to do it now.  I'm actually using Recoil for state because I like shiny things :)

Comment: Great, personally I am not a fan of using state management libraries, I use the built-in Context API and custom hooks.